# jquery validation for dropdown login form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Login form with validation is working perfectly when i execute it independently...but when it is merged with the slider code, the form is only being displayed, validation of the form is not working...Please someone help me out..Here's my code...(it is a drop down login form)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="iview.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css" />
    <style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="loginbut/js/login.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#loginForm").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: "specify email"
        },
        password: {
            required: "specify password"
        }
    }
});

// Login Form

$(function() {
var button = $('#loginButton');
var box = $('#loginBox');
var form = $('#loginForm');
button.removeAttr('href');
button.mouseup(function(login) {
    box.toggle();
    button.toggleClass('active');
});
form.mouseup(function() { 
    return false;
});
$(this).mouseup(function(login) {
    if(!($(login.target).parent('#loginButton').length > 0)) {
        button.removeClass('active');
        box.hide();
    }
});
});


});

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <br/>
<br/>

<div id="bar">
    <div id="container">
        <!-- Login Starts Here -->
        <div id="loginContainer">
            <a href="#" id="loginButton"><span>Login</span><em></em></a>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <div id="loginBox">                
                <form id="loginForm">
                    <fieldset id="body">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <input type="submit" id="login" value="Sign in" />
                        <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"    />Remember me</label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <span><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Login Ends Here -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div id="iview">
        <div data-iview:image="1.jpg" data-iview:transition="slice-top-      fade,slice-right-fade">
    <div class="iview-caption caption1" data-x="80" data-y="200">iView<sup>&trade;</sup></div>
            <div class="iview-caption" data-x="80" data-y="275" data-transition="wipeRight">The world's most awesome jQuery Image & Content Slider</div>
            <div class="iview-caption" data-x="254" data-y="320" data-transition="wipeLeft"><i>Presented by <b>Hemn Chawroka</b></i></div>
        </div>

        <div data-iview:image="2.jpg" data-iview:transition="zigzag-top,strip-left-fade" data-iview:pausetime="3000">
            <div class="iview-caption caption5" data-x="60" data-y="280" data-transition="wipeDown">Captions can be positioned and resized freely</div>
            <div class="iview-caption caption6" data-x="300" data-y="350" data-transition="wipeUp"><a href="#">Example URL-link</a></div>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript" src="fullscreen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#background-image").fullscreenBackground();
});
</script>



    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="easing.js"></script>


    <script src="iview.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#iview').iView({
                pauseTime: 7000,
                directionNav: false,
                controlNav: true,
                tooltipY: -15
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just guess, try to remove wrapped `$(function() {...}` on your // login form functionality part, or move it outside of document ready, it is generally the same thing

Comment: Thanks..tried that already..but it's not working

Comment: Explain exactly what you mean by "validation is not working".  How are we supposed to know what you mean by "slider code"?  Please don't make us guess what plugins you're using and also construct a jsFiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

Your form Validation is working with the code as you've posted it...

http://jsfiddle.net/sNCds/

Please provide more information about what "validation is not working" means.

You've also included jQuery a second time near the bottom of your page.  If this is part of the "slider code" you're talking about that you've added, then it's likely what's breaking everything.  You should not use more than one version of jQuery on your page at a time.  You've already included jQuery once at the top of the page (version 1.8.3) which is adequate for everything below it.

Remove this line...

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```